# obj. mtl. model keeps importing with half the car looking and staying pitch black

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, normals

I'm fairly new to Blender so maybe I'm just missing something simple I hope. When I import the car model in with both the files obj. and mtl. it imports but it does so as shown below. I read online somewhere to clear the custom split normals data but whenever i do that the object in question gets rigid and i don't know where to even start with fixing that. [image][image][image: rigid window]

[image]

Comment: It looks as if your second image has Face Orientation enabled in the Viewport Overlay menu. If so, the normals are inverted on the Red areas of your car. Select one of the objects which are red, go into Edit mode and then use Shift-N to invert the normals. If that turns the object blue, you'll have to do the same for all the other red objects which should sort the problem and mean that all the normals are correctly facing outwards.

Comment: Yeah I turned that on to better see what I was talking about. I tired that suggestion but it didn't do anything unfortunately. I saw the pop up message for the normals recalculating but nothing else changed

Comment: You could try Alt-N > Flip or Recalculate Outside to see if that helps, but I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it. As long as it's not over 30 Meg pack any image files with File > External Data > Pack Resources before sharing.

Comment: Added the file .

Comment: No idea what program that model was made in but every object has multiple duplicate vertices on it which is stopping the face orientation being recalculated correctly and you have to increase the Merge Distance to 0.001m to get rid of all the duplicates. However, even when the orientation is corrected (with Alt-N > Recalculate Outside), the shading is still different on different panels whether you're in Solid mode or Rendered view (after adding lighting) despite each using the same material and settings so I'm afraid I've no idea what's causing it.